# Will my app i'm building be breaching any copyright laws

Tags: copyright, music

Currently building an app where it may include copyrighted words as its running like a karaoke type app

With it including things that are copyrighted what can I do in regards to this?

Comment: In which country?

Comment: Individual words are not generally subject to copyright.  For example, the fact that someone has copyright on a book or article containing the word "automobile" does not prevent you from using the word "automobile" in your application.

Comment: What do you mean "it may include copyrighted words." Are you including copyrighted material (e.g. lyrics) in your karaoke app or aren't you?

Comment: Words can't be copyrighted.  Sequences of words (like sentences) can be, if they're original.  Given that you're talking karaoke, you probably are thinking of including song lyrics, which are long enough and original enough to be copyrighted.

Comment: I'm currently in the uk and it will include copyrighted words wasn't sure prior if all lyrics were copyrighted.

Answer (score 2):

> With it including things that are copyrighted what can I do in regards
>   to this?

Either (somewhat depending on jurisdiction):

1) license or get permission to use the copyrighted material (which I assume is music re: your reference to karaoke), or

2) be in violation of copyright, and possibly be the subject of a copyright infringement lawsuit.

And read **[I have a question about copyright. What should I read before I ask it?](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/i-have-a-question-about-copyright-what-should-i-read-before-i-ask-it)**